# What does convolution do on embedding axis in NLP?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network, word-embedding

I'm try to understanding what convolution neural network does in NLP.

For example, my input sentence matrix has dimension (100,200). Here 100 is the length of my sentence, 200 is the dimension of word embedding.

Then I used convolution layer to extract feature. In Keras, something like `Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh', strides=1)`.

**But why the output dimension is (100,128)?** I can understand the first number, because I use padding same, and stride 1, so the dimension should be the same. **But why the second dimension is 128, shouldn't it be 200*128?** What does the kernel actually look like? I'm assuming it only scan along the sentence, but why the embedding dimension get lost, the kernel just summed it up?

I add a picture to illustrate it better. If it is a 1D kernel, and do convolution over the word sequence, why after convolution the word embedding dimension becomes 1(shown in picture)? That doesn't make sense to me.

[image]

Comment: Can you put the source of the figure, please?

Answer (score 0):

All standard layers work like this. The output dim is the same as the filters.

It would be really hard to control anything if it wasn't like this.

Have you ever seen the basics on neural networks teaching how a fully connected layer works?

Each neuron in a layer gets all inputs, multiply them by weights **and sum** them:

```
neuron1Out = in1*W11 + in2*W12 + in3*W13 + bias1   
neuron2Out = in1*W21 + in2*W22 + in3*W23 + bias2
```

This is what a `Dense(2)` outputs when it gets an `input_dim=3`.

The weight matrix is shaped as `(3,2)`, one dimension for the inputs, another for the outputs, and the mathematical operation is a matrix multiplication with the inputs.

Convolutions do almost exactly the same. The difference is that it repeats the operation over an over and over bringing results for each pixel.

The shape of the kernel is `(kernelXpixels, kernelYpixels, input_channels, output_channels)`, which is `(3,3,200,128)` in your example.

After multiplying each of the 200 input channels with each of the 200 slices of weights, **the results are summed** into a single output. This is done 128 times, bringing 128 output neurons/channels.

Comment: OK, so are the 200 slice have same weight?

Comment: No, one group of 3x3 weights for each input channel. After multiplying each group by each input channel, "they're summed" (this eliminates the 200). Everything done 180 times with different weights, creating the 180 outputs.

Comment: OK, then how is the weigh determined, are they fixed value or learned from training?

Comment: Learned from training